# LINQ2SQL problem when inserting object from a derived class

Tags: linq-to-sql

Im getting an exception when trying to add a L2SQL into the DataContext

"Unable to find key member litterId for key litterId in type Rat. The key may be incorrect or the name of the field or property of the Rat may have changed."

Here is the code that triggers it:

```
    Rat petty = new Rat();
    petty.PetName = "Ratty";
    dc.Pets.InsertOnSubmit(petty);
```

Rat is a class that derives from Pet. I can insert Pet objects with no problem. I have made the inheritance acording to specifications in the MSDN with the L2SQL O/R designer.

Comment: I think everything in linq2Sql must have a primary key.

Comment: Please post the relevant code for `Pet` and `Rat`.

Comment: No, derived classes cannot have a primary key. The use the same table as the base class.

Comment: I solved it myself. It was cause i hidd the fk connection. It was set to private. :P